# Rewrite I2C control C function to Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I'm trying to rewrite `C` code to python, but I'm not sure how to express this part in python

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define EEPROM_write(address, p) {int i = 0; byte *pp = (byte*)&(p);for(; i < sizeof(p); i++) EEPROM.write(address+i, pp[i]);}
```

I think I should use `I2C` object from `machine`, but I'm not sure what is going on in the `C` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect the macro line:

`#define`

This is the preprocessor command to define a macro.

`EEPROM_write(address, p)`

The macro is named "EEPROM_write" and it takes two arguments, "address" and "p". Since the preprocessor is mostly working here as a search-and-replace mechanism, there are no types. They depend on the site where the macro is used.

```c
{
    int i = 0;
    byte *pp = (byte*)&(p);
    for (; i < sizeof(p); i++)
        EEPROM.write(address+i, pp[i]);
}
```

This is the formatted C code of the replacement. It consist of a single block of statements, and the preprocessor will replace each occurence of `address` and `p` with the arguments given at the usage of the macro.

The code block takes the address of `p` as a `byte` pointer. Then it loops through all bytes of `p` (including padding) and calls `EEPROM.write()` with consecutive addresses (starting at `address`) and the respective byte of `p`.